# Custom SPClaimProvider with Context Impersonation throwing exception

Tags: claims-based-auth, impersonation

I have written a custom SPClaimProvider for my SharePoint 2010 site. It seemed to be working for couple of days and it started throwing exception whenever I elevate the privileges or user Context Impersonation (using a Windows user). The exception details are below:

```
Source: Microsoft.SharePoint  Message: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.  Trace:   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserToken.GetClaimsUserLoginName()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.CopyUserToken(SPUserToken userToken)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.SPSiteConstructor(SPFarm farm, Guid applicationId, Guid contentDatabaseId, Guid siteId, Guid siteSubscriptionId, SPUrlZone zone, Uri requestUri, String serverRelativeUrl, Boolean hostHeaderIsSiteName, SPUserToken userToken)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone, SPUserToken userToken)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPUrlZone zone, SPUserToken userToken)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPUserToken userToken)    
 at IHI.Springs.GAC.Security.HttpContextImpersonation.ImpersonateSite()
```

Does anyone know what I am missing here?

Comment: It seems GetClaimsUserLoginName() is a custom extension method. You should contact the author of that method.

I will add that you cannot just create an SPUserToken with just a login name. You can save the token from a session where the user has logged in, or get a token for an IIdentity object. (And to get the IIdentity, you need a password...)

Comment: Check this - https://stevenderveaux.wordpress.com/2010/09/13/operation-is-not-valid-due-to-the-current-state-of-the-object/

Comment: This post says claims token expires in 24 hours. (you can also see InvalidOperationException error when checking user's permission from UI).  http://designerworkflow.blogspot.com/2014/02/operation-is-not-valid-due-to-current.html

Comment: I'm getting the same error message and although it's been 10 years since this was created it's still the only valid hit i'm getting on google while the links shared don't help. Can someone remember what helped here?